# Storing Javascript object in Wordpress User Database

Tags: javascript, database, wordpress

I am working on a page where user can create his own unique , personalized week schedule.

Right know all about the schedule is stored in javascript object - scheduleArray.

[Here is the site with my work so far](http://www.traineffective.com/schedule/)

How can I store this javascript object to logged user database in WP?

I need to load it from database on site init, and later when user clicks "SUBMIT" button store it back to database.

Could you provide me any ideas, tutorials from which I can start on ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one way - add field (maybe something like next https://tommcfarlin.com/add-custom-user-meta-during-registration/) to user profile and store JSON here.

When yser submit form - you can create hidden field with this (by "onsubmit" event) and write to user field by server-side script.